# Get reference to appended object in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this simple html structure : (example for simplicity)

```
<div class='a'/>
 <div class='b'/>      <---┐  
 <div class='c'/>      <---├─  those 2 are dynamicly inserted
```

Important  : this structure is occurring multiple times in my page , and the only thing I know is the **first** div '`.a`'.

I need to find the div `'b'` which (must be) immediately next to `'a'`

And I need to find the div `'c'` which (must be) immediately  next to `'b'`

*notice : I don't need `.a`. it is only an anchor for finding the next items.*

So  , assume `obj` is `$(".a")` - I did :

`obj.next(".b").add(  obj.next(".b").next(".c") );`

But  here - `obj.next` is calculated twice.

[image]

**Question :**

Is there any way to replace the yellow part with a reference to the blue part ?

*(cached variable is also valid solution ,but i'm wondering if jquery allows the get a reference to the appended elements).*

Comment: it looks like `obj.find(' > .b > .c')` to me

Comment: @arun , even if it was , still your selector wont return b and c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
var obj = $(".a");
obj.next('.b').next('.c').addBack().html(function () {
    return this.className
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9w3Ba/)

Comment: No , sorry for making it look like it , i clarified . They are all siblings

Comment: Very nice. :-) ....however I builidng a plugin and im afraid that it wont be supported cuz of andSelf vs addBack....

Comment: Im choosing the answer cuz it does provide the immediate next's. As opposed to other helpful solutions

Answer (score 1):

What about this,

```
obj.nextUntil(".c").not(obj);
```

or

```
obj.siblings('.b,.c')
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3RbS5/1/)

Comment: nextUntil is _not including the element_ and I do need .c.

Comment: @RoyiNamir is this ok for your context.?

Comment: Its ok but it doesn't guarantee to get the immediate sibling and its next immediate sibling

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
    var _b = obj.next(".b");
    _b.next(".c");
```

is this what you want

```
 obj.nextAll('.b,.c')
```